# clojure update value during doseq

Tags: clojure

what is the best way to update / calculate a variable during doseq?

Obviously I could just do the following:

```
(doseq [x xs]
        (println (string/join " " x)))
(println "total:" (reduce + 0 (map count xs)))
```

But I want to avoid having to map over the entire list at the end to calculate a value... It makes more sense to just update a count as we iterate.

I found that this *works*, but it seems like a bit of a cludge.

```
(defn display-xs [xs]
  ;; all I want to do is update a count while I print,
  ;; and have that value available afterwards!
  (let [n (ref 0)]
    (do
      (doseq [x xs]
        (dosync
         (ref-set n (+ @n (count x)))
         (println (string/join " " x))))
      (println "total:" @n))))
```

I know that `doseq` allows for `:let` but I need the value after doseq is finished.

Or

```
(println "total:" (reduce (fn [m x] (do (println x) (+ m (count x)))) 0 xs))
```

Comment: I would not be bothered by the first version if I were you. Unless you are looking for performance (in which case, benchmark).

Comment: Your snippet at the end with `reduce` seems perfectly good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worry about the at most miniscule overhead of looping.  It is much more important to separate different tasks.  I quite like your first version.

Your second version could look better, but I'd still prefer the first.

```
(defn display-xs [xs]
  (let [n (atom 0)]
    (doseq [x xs]
      (swap! n + (count x))
      (println (string/join " " x)))
    (println "total: " @n)))
```

Comment: The problem with iterating twice is not the minuscule computational overhead, but the fact that now you are not processing the list lazily, and it must all be kept in memory at once so you can re-count it. Consider a short sequence of large elements, such as `(repeatedly 1000 #(make-array Object 1000000))`. You don't want to shove 1GB into RAM at once when you could do it in chunks of 1MB.

Comment: OK, I can understand that, provided a sufficient size.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a little bit so show how I would do it:

```
(def sample-vals (repeatedly 10 #(range (+ 5 (rand-int 10)))))

(defn display-xs [xs]
  (let [n (atom 0)]
    (doseq [x xs]
       (swap! n + (count x))
       (println x))
    (println "total:" @n)))

(newline)
(display-xs sample-vals)

(defn print-n-sum [cum coll]
  (let [cnt  (count coll) ]
     (printf "%4d:  " cnt)
     (println  coll)
     (+ cum cnt)))

(defn calc-sum [xs]
  (let [n (reduce print-n-sum 0 xs) ]
    (println "total:" n)))

(newline)
(calc-sum sample-vals)
```

with result

```
> rs; lein run
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
(0 1 2 3 4)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
(0 1 2 3 4 5)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
total: 97

  10:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
  12:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
  11:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
  12:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
   5:  (0 1 2 3 4)
  12:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
   6:  (0 1 2 3 4 5)
  11:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
   7:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
  11:  (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
total: 97
```

Note that you don't have to use an atom (simpler than a ref for this example).  You could do the printing and adding in a single function like `print-n-sum` that you feed to `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

You can print it in your reduce append function

```
(defn print-and-append [acc x]
      (println (string/join " " x))
      (+ acc (count x)))

(println (reduce print-and-append 0 xs))
```